# Refreshing bash prompt after calling bind -x command

Tags: bash, readline

I have a bash function that changes the directory of my current bash session. I'd like to call the function by pressing Alt-M and am using `bind -x` to create this mapping. After entering Alt-M on my keyboard, nothing happens in my bash prompt - there is no new line as there would be if a function were typed and then Enter was pressed. I have to press Enter again to get a new prompt on a new line.

How can I force there to be a new prompt on a new line? If I call the function directly/normally (i.e. by typing `foo` and then hitting enter), the command will work as expected and there will be a bash prompt on a new line, with a refreshed PS1.

Using `echo` or `printf` commands in the function doesn't work - it prints a new line, but above the bash prompt, and the bash prompt doesn't refresh. What exactly is not happening here that I want to happen?

```
foo(){
    dir="/some/path"
    cd $dir
}

bind -x '"\em": foo'
```

Comment: I suspect the space after the `:` character is not allowed - `help bind` says `-x  keyseq:shell-command`.

Comment: i dont think this is possible. the prompt is waiting for the user to input a command. it'll not reprompt unless ENTER is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a macro instead of a shell function, you can inject a return keypress:

```
bind '"\em": "\C-ex\C-u foo\C-m\C-y\C-b\C-d"'
```

- `\C-e` moves to end of line
- `x` appends something to ensure line is not empty
- `\C-u` deletes the line and saves it in the kill ring
- `foo` is the command - leading space stops it getting added to history (assuming `HISTCONTROL=ignorespace`)
- `\C-m` injects the return keypress
- `\C-y` restores the original line
- `\C-b\C-d` removes the extraneous `x` we added

I don't know how to move the cursor back to its original position if it wasn't at end of line. Also the kill ring gets polluted.